# Receiving "file not found" Zend PDF

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, zend-pdf

The below code is a sample and it works (loads pdf from file, draws a single string, Success), however if I change the invoice.pdf (example pdf from a tutorial) to my pdf, buyersguide.pdf I receive an error on firefox, File not found.

```
    <?php
   header("Content-Type: application/x-pdf");
   //header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=invoice-". date("Y-m-d-H-i") . ".pdf");
   header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");

   require_once 'zendframework/library/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
   //Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();   

   $loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

   // load the invoice

   $invoice = Zend_Pdf::load("invoice.pdf");
   $page = $invoice->pages[0];


   $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES_BOLD);

   $page->setFont($font, 12);

   // invoice information*/
   $page->drawText('success ', 420,642);

   // output the PDF
   echo $invoice->render();
?>
```

Code with filename changed:

```
    <?php
   header("Content-Type: application/x-pdf");
   //header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=invoice-". date("Y-m-d-H-i") . ".pdf");
   header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");

   require_once 'zendframework/library/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
   //Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();   

   $loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

   // load the invoice

   $invoice = Zend_Pdf::load("buyersguide.pdf");
   $page = $invoice->pages[0];


   $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES_BOLD);

   $page->setFont($font, 12);

   // invoice information*/
   $page->drawText('success ', 420,642);

   // output the PDF
   echo $invoice->render();
?>
```

PDF for buyers guide is taken from a government website. PDF loads normally in adobe reader. Buyers guide PDF: http://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/pdf-0083-buyers-guide.pdf

Comment: Worked for me with ZF 1.11.11. Try saving the contents of the render() operation to a file and see what happens. If the file is OK then try re-instating the header that you've got commented out and see what happens.

Comment: Retested and still not working. Are you using the buyers guide pdf from the link?

I'm not sure how to save the contents of the render to a file, I attempted: 

 $pdfString = $invoice->render();
 $handle = fopen("$filename-$time.txt", "w");
 fwrite($handle, $pdfString);
 fclose($handle);

I also attempted to save the pdf to my server and test that and it isn't working at all. It does however work perfectly when saving the demonstration invoice.pdf

Comment: See my updated response in my answer below. I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following code demonstrates that the latest stable version of ZF1 (1.12.3) will successfully process the file that you are having trouble with:

```
<?php
set_include_path("PATH/TO/zf1/library" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

// Grab a copy of the file from the remote server
// This is just for demo purposes only
// Obviously you'd want to keep a copy of this file locally
$source = "http://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/pdf-0083-buyers-guide.pdf";
file_put_contents("template.pdf", file_get_contents($source));

// load the invoice
$invoice = Zend_Pdf::load("template.pdf");
$page = $invoice->pages[0];

$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES_BOLD);

$page->setFont($font, 12);

// invoice information*/
$page->drawText("success ", 320, 700);

// Save the file to disk
$filename = "invoice-" . date("Y-m-d-H-i") . ".pdf";
file_put_contents($filename, $invoice->render());

// output the PDF
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"" );
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize( $filename ));
readfile( $filename );
```

This code is far from production-ready, but it works. If it doesn't work for you then you should print out the return codes of every single function call until you determine which line is failing.

Comment: Confirmed, the code you posted works perfectly on my server. Thanks for your help! Still trying to determine what was wrong with my original code. I think I can just work from yours to determine where to go next. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry to be a pest, but if you deem it worthy, would you mind officially accepting my answer? Thank you.